# Variable indefinida y validar formato de fecha en php

Tags: php

Estoy intentando validar un formulario y tengo problema con la fecha de nacimiento. He buscado en el manual de php y no logro hacer que funcione. También la variable `$primeravez` sale como indefinida: he intentado meterla en un `if` con `isset` pero no lo logro.

```php
function validarFecha($date, $format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

if (!$primeravez)
{
        
    //fecha de nacimiento (revisar)
    $date = $_POST["nacimiento"];
    echo $date, "<br>";
    if (empty($_POST["nacimiento"])) {
        echo "<p>Falta rellenar el campo de fecha de nacimiento</p>";
    } elseif (validarFecha($date, $format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s')){
        return true;
    }else{
        echo "La fecha no esta correctamente definida";
        return false;
    }

    //dni (revisar)
    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
    if (empty($_POST["dni"])) {
        echo "<p>Falta rellenar el campo de DNI</p>";
    }elseif (strlen($dni) < 8) {
        echo "<p>El campo DNI debe contener mas de 8 caracteres</p>";
    }elseif (ucfirst($dni)){
        echo "la primera letra debe estar en mayúscula";
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está la definición de la variable que mencionas? No olvides que tu código debe ser un [repro].

Comment: esto esta mál: `elseif (validarFecha($date, $format = 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s'))`.  Prueba a dejarlo así: `elseif (validarFecha($date))` o ponle un formato distinto de este modo: `elseif (validarFecha($date, 'd-m-Y\TH:i:s'))`

Comment: si disculpa, me falto eso para la variable, creo q ya funciona correctamente
$primeravez = false;
if (empty($_POST["botEnviar"])){
    $primeravez = true;
}

if ($primeravez

Comment: @masterguru no me funciono el código para la fecha de nacimiento, no se que estare haciendo mal

Comment: Pon un ejemplo del código de esa fecha de nacimiento que le estas pasando, o sea, un ejemplo del `$_POST["nacimiento"]`que recibe para ver su formato

Comment: he probado, 04/06/1985, 04-06-1985, sin los ceros también, los meses en letras y nada

Comment: Creo q ya pude solucionarlo, le quite el \TH:i:s solo necestio la fecha no la hora 

Un millon de gracias, me ha servido de mucho crack

Comment: Efectivamente a eso iba, a modificar ese formato. Bien hecho!  Saludos!

Comment: Esto son claramente 2 preguntas. Plantéalas como tal la próxima vez.

Comment: si disculpe mis errores, aun aprendiendo, muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 0):

En cuento a tu condicional, usa el ["operador de fusión de null"](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php) (PHP7 y superiores).

```
if (!($primeravez ?? false)) {
    ...
}
```

donde le indicas que si la variable no esta definida o vale null, tome como valor `false`. Sería lo mismo que escribir:

```
if (!($primeravez = (isset($primeravez)) 
    ? $primeravez
    : false)) {
    ...
}
```

Esto sólo evita que la ejecución del programa produzca un error, pero si esa variable en algún momento debe existir y no la has definido tendrás un error de lógica.

Para el formato de fechas, esto nunca lo había visto `\T`.
Lo habitual sería: `$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';`